# Why did The Professor have Lisbon taken to the robbery location instead of his secret place?

Tags: plot-explanation, money-heist

In *Money Heist* S04E08, we see that *Professor* and his miner friends successfully perform an escape plan and rescue *Lisbon* from the court location. But after the rescue, instead of taking *Lisbon* (his lover) to his place, he ordered *Marseille* to take her to the robbery location (with so much effort).

What is the point of putting her in the robbery location? If he wanted to humiliate the police, that rescue plan would perfectly do that and taking Lisbon to the bank seemed to be immoderate.

We know that before Lisbon's arrest, she and Professor had the role of guiding the robbery from the outside. Wasn't it more reasonable to take her to himself as an assistant like before instead of putting her in another misery?

Answer (score 1):

Because they were using an Army helicopter and that can be easily tracked.
And while getting back to the professor police can catch both of them.

The more secured place than Professor's secret place is Bank itself. We saw it in end of the Season 4 when lady inspector catch the Professor.

Comment: That, or because this is Money Heist and sometimes the story doesn't make sense ; especially in seasons 3 & 4...

Comment: Maybe it was the plan in case someone got caught, like professor often does.

Comment: Professor himself chosed the military helicopter to dramatize the scene! There was NO pressure on him to choose that! So he could easily transfer her to another place just with a car

Answer (score 1):

Part of the underlying theme in seasons 3 and 4 is that the team is weaker when divided. Rio and Tokyo splitting up causes the entire chain of events. This division applies literally and figuratively in several cases (Rio/Tokyo, Professor/Lisbon arguments, Palermo power struggle, Denver/Stockholm breaking up, ...).

The end of season 4 marks a literal and figurative coming together of the team, rising above the divisions they were faced with.

Secondly, at the moment the Bank of Spain is essentially the only fortress under their control. While that of course cannot last, we have 4 seasons of proof that the team plays a high stakes game and innately relies on the fact *that* they will get out, and that they are in it *together*.

Based on those assumptions, Lisbon is as safe inside the bank as she is outside - let alone that they are considerably less vulnerable inside the bank for as long as they hold it.

Thirdly, Lisbon getting captured and the Professor needing to actively flee constantly proves that it's really dangerous for them outside of the bank. Having Lisbon inside ensures that she is a backup in case the Professor is caught next. Having the Professor and Lisbon together puts the eggs in one basket, which would be foolish to repeat after it already failed them once.

Answer (score 1):

Initially the plan was Lisbon and the Professor had to guide the robbery from the outside. But you can observe that Lisbon can be easily disturbed.You can observe that

1. For the first time when Alicia talked with professor and Lisbon, she targeted Lisbon and Lisbon got deviated from the plan and Alicia has the upper hand after that call. Even Professor said the same with Lisbon that "Alicia is targeting you because you are the weak link".
2. After Lisbon got caught, Alicia interrogated Lisbon. After the police came to know about the location of her daughter and mother, she was about to tell the entire plan to Alicia which was later stopped by Antonzas.
3. Also Nairobi got died, someone must be there to fill the void that was created by her loss.

   So, Professor might thought that placing Lisbon in the robbery location will make much good to the plan than keeping her with him and working together.